# Issue with <select ng-options="..." />

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to achieve a simple feature with AngularJS as below. In item list, when user clicks an item and click the Remove button then the item will be removed.

[image]

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div>
      <select ng-options="item.name for item in items" ng-model="currentItem" size="5" style="width: 200px"></select>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="removeItem()">Remove</button>
  </div>
```

and script is like below:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      name: 'item1'
    }, {
      name: 'item2'
    }, {
      name: 'item3'
    }];

    $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[0];

    $scope.removeItem = function() {
      var index = $scope.items.indexOf($scope.currentItem);
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    };

  });
```

The problem is when I tried to remove an item (i.e. item2), the list always shows an empty item in the first position. When I click 'item1' or 'item3', the empty item disappears.

[image]

I know that this is caused by `ng-model="currentItem"` in html. The item that currentItem points to get removed, currentItem points to null. So I changed the function removeItem as below to solve this issue.

```
$scope.removeItem = function() {
      var index = $scope.items.indexOf($scope.currentItem);
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);

      /* PART 1 begin */
      if ($scope.items.length === 0) {
        $scope.currentItem = null;
      } else {
        if (index >= 0 && index <= $scope.items.length - 1) {
          $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[index];
        } else {
          $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[$scope.items.length - 1];
        }
      }
      /* PART 1 end */
    };
```

I would like to know whether there is any simple way (like a directive) in AngularJS to do the action in PART 1 automatically.

Comment: I've done this before, too. I don't know of a better way.

Comment: did you try to add an ng-if in the select? like  `<select ng-if="currentItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items" ng-model="currentItem" size="5" style="width: 200px"></select>`

Comment: I tried ng-if but it's still the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is simple way in which you can prevent that is just include

```
 <option value="" ng-show="false"></option>
```

in select like as shown below

```
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in items" ng-model="currentItem" size="5" style="width: 200px">
   <option value="" ng-show="false"></option>
</select>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5rb4zsxo/)**

**UPDATE 1**

I have resolved the issue of not highlighting the last item, Take a look the working demo

```
$scope.removeItem = function () {
    var index = $scope.items.indexOf($scope.currentItem);
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    index === $scope.items.length ? $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[index - 1] : $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[index];
};
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5rb4zsxo/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There is one thing I noticed that when user removes any item, the currentItem always points to the last one in the list without highlighting it. For example, if I remove item1, it looks like no item is highlighted. But actually item3 is the current item and when I click 'Remove' button again, item3 gets removed.